# Scheduled Apex in waiting for more than a week

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

I have a couple of scheduled apex jobs which were all running smoothly. But since the beginning of this year pretty much all of them are having CronTrigger state as waiting. Some of them for more than a week. Is the problem on Salesforce side? Will it resolve itself or should I delete existing scheduled jobs and relaunch them?

Comment: How are these scheduled; one off execution with an offset from "now"? If so it could be because of [this](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdesgUAB/scheduling-a-job-in-the-near-future-is-not-guaranteed-to-work). Regardless, abort the jobs and reschedule them. They are unlikely to come back to life.

Comment: Double-check they are being scheduled for a future date and time. If scheduled by code, check that this is handling setting the year correctly (when the year is changing).

Comment: @PhilW The schedules are not one off, some of them are every hour of every day, some once a week and some once a month, there are scheduled by launching them from Anonymous execute, an example would be: System.schedule('LogCleaner', '0 30 0 2 * ? * ', new LogCleaner()); -> 2nd of every month

Comment: Fair enough. That cron expression looks fine to run stuff at 00:30 on the second of each month. It sounds like a Salesforce glitch has got you. Do what you suggested and abort then reschedule them.

Answer (score 1):

This happens in two occasions which I have faced while working on salesforce platoform for 13 years.

1. If 'Flex queue' gets full ( more than 100 ) jobs waiting/holding at a time, in this scenario sometime scheduled jobs gets corrupted.
2. Salesforce server side glitch. it's rare although it happens.

#1 Happens a lot. In my company we are building some mechanism as to avoid this situation. However solution is to delete scheduled jobs and relaunch/reSchedule them.

#2 is rare, but you can connect with Salesforce support and then will help you out.